# Activating a function when pageshow jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a function within a jquery pageshow function and only should be activated when on a certain page (id). But for some reason it doesn't run that script. The pages are dynamic with id's.

### **Here is a sample of my code**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#fragment-1', function() {    
        $.mobile.activePage.find("div [data-role=tabs] ul li:first-child a").click();

        createCheckboxes('#fragment-2')

});

function createCheckboxes(into){

        var players_names = playerCal("ars", 7, 5);
         $("#createBtn").remove();
         $(into).append('<fieldset class="cbFieldSet" data-role="controlgroup">');
         var length = players_names[0].length;
         $(".cbFieldSet").append("<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='d' data-divider-theme='e' data-count-theme='b'><li data-role='list-divider'><span>Select players in the next line up2</span></li></li>");
         for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
            $(".cbFieldSet").append('<li><input type="checkbox" name="cb-'+i+'" id="cb-'+i+'" value="'+players_names[0][i]+'"/><label for="cb-'+i+'">'+players_names[0][i]+'</label></li>');
         }

          $(".cbFieldSet").append("</ul>");

         $(into).trigger("create");
         $("#showBtn").css("visibility","visible");
         console.log(players_names);
        }
```

**Sample of my dynamic page, it works**

```
+"<div id='fragment-1'>"
      + "<form>"
      + "<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' class = 'content'>"
      + "</fieldset>"
      + "</form>"
      + "</div>"
      + "<div id='fragment-2'>"
     + "<form>"
      + "<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' class = 'content'>"
      + "</fieldset>"
      + "</form>"
      + "</div></div></div>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like when someone creates clean and readable question.

You have an error in your code, div holding your page is not propperly formed jQUery Mobile page.

Change this:

```
<div id='fragment-1'>
```

To this:

```
<div id='fragment-1' data-role="page">
```

Page events works only on div containers with attribute **data-role="page"**.

### Update:

Working example made from your/my previous example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/55/

Comment: I tried this and still gives me the same results as before, empty

Comment: Look at my updated answer, it the same thing I told you to do. Tell me where are you appending new pages?